# Create AD user and add to group at the same time?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

I know how to create an AD B2C user, as well as add them to a group via the graph API. I'm doing this in my Azure Function. What I'm wondering is, is it possible to create the user and add them to the group at the same time? If not, then I suppose I'll have to handle the potential case of a user being created but failing to be added to a group. How likely is this sort of scenario? I'm trying to make sure I cover all my bases for all failure conditions, so any input would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to use [Batch Processing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-batch-processing) for these kinds of requests.

Here is the sample request they post in the article:
The following example shows a batch request that contains five items:

1. A change set that creates a user, testuser@contoso.onmicrosoft.com (POST). This operation includes the Prefer: response-no-content header to suppress the newly created user being returned.
2. A change set that updates the Department and Job Title properties of the new user (PATCH), and sets its manager navigation property (PUT).
3. A query for the manager of the new user (GET).
4. A change set that deletes the new user (DELETE).
5. A query for the user (GET). This operation will fail because the user was deleted in the previous step.

   ```
   POST https://graph.windows.net/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/$batch?api-version=1.5 HTTP/1.1
   Authorization: Bearer ey … jQA
   Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_36522ad7-fc75-4b56-8c71-56071383e77b 
   Host: graph.windows.net
   Content-Length: 2961

   --batch_36522ad7-fc75-4b56-8c71-56071383e77b 
   Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_77162fcd-b8da-41ac-a9f8-9357efbbd620 
   Content-Length: 631       

   --changeset_77162fcd-b8da-41ac-a9f8-9357efbbd620 
   Content-Type: application/http 
   Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary 

   POST /contoso.onmicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.5 HTTP/1.1
   Content-Type: application/json
   Accept: application/json
   Content-Length: 256
   Prefer: return-no-content
   Host: graph.windows.net

   {
       "accountEnabled": true,
       "displayName": "Test User",
       "mailNickname": "testuser",
       "passwordProfile": { "password" : "Test1234", "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false },
       "userPrincipalName": "testuser@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
   }

   --changeset_77162fcd-b8da-41ac-a9f8-9357efbbd620----batch_36522ad7-fc75-4b56-8c71-56071383e77b 
   Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_4b2cbfb7-011d-4edb-8bbf-e044f9830aaf 
   Content-Length: 909

   --changeset_4b2cbfb7-011d-4edb-8bbf-e044f9830aaf 
   Content-Type: application/http 
   Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary 

   PATCH /contoso.onmicrosoft.com/users/testuser@contoso.onmicrosoft.com?api-version=1.5 HTTP/1.1
   Content-Type: application/json
   Accept: application/json
   Content-Length: 72
   Host: graph.windows.net

   {
       "department": "Engineering",
       "jobTitle": "Test Engineer"
   }

   --changeset_4b2cbfb7-011d-4edb-8bbf-e044f9830aaf 
   Content-Type: application/http 
   Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary 

   PUT /contoso.onmicrosoft.com/users/testuser@contoso.onmicrosoft.com/$links/manager?api-version=1.5 HTTP/1.1
   Content-Type: application/json
   Accept: application/json
   Content-Length: 112
   Host: graph.windows.net

   {
     "url":"https://graph.windows.net/contoso.onmicrosoft.com/users/a71e4d1c-ce99-40dc-8d4b-390eac63e039"
   }

   --changeset_4b2cbfb7-011d-4edb-8bbf-e044f9830aaf----batch_36522ad7-fc75-4b56-8c71-56071383e77b 
   Content-Type: application/http 
   Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary

   GET /contoso.onmicrosoft.com/users/testuser@contoso.onmicrosoft.com/$links/manager?api-version=1.5 HTTP/1.1
   Accept: application/json
   Host: graph.windows.net

   --batch_36522ad7-fc75-4b56-8c71-56071383e77b 
   Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=changeset_9a0b5878-0f4a-4f57-91c5-9792cdd5ef20 
   Content-Length: 331       

   --changeset_9a0b5878-0f4a-4f57-91c5-9792cdd5ef20 
   Content-Type: application/http 
   Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary 

   DELETE /contoso.onmicrosoft.com/users/testuser@contoso.onmicrosoft.com?api-version=1.5 HTTP/1.1
   Accept: application/json
   Host: graph.windows.net


   --changeset_9a0b5878-0f4a-4f57-91c5-9792cdd5ef20----batch_36522ad7-fc75-4b56-8c71-56071383e77b 
   Content-Type: application/http 
   Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary

   GET /contoso.onmicrosoft.com/users/testuser@contoso.onmicrosoft.com?api-version=1.5 HTTP/1.1
   Accept: application/json
   Host: graph.windows.net

   --batch_36522ad7-fc75-4b56-8c71-56071383e77b--
   ```